# How requirejs load commonjs packages?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, single-page-application

I follow http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages to learn how RequireJs load CommonJS modules, but I can't get it.

I have below file.

foo/foo.js
main.js
require.js

foo/foo.js with content:

```
exports.bar = '1234';
exports.xyz = function noop() {};
```

main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    packages: [{name:'foo', main: 'foo'}]
});

require(['foo'], function(foo) {
   console.log(foo.bar);
});
```

It said can't read bar of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You've missed an important part of the documentation you link to in your question:

> While the packages can have the CommonJS directory layout, **the modules themselves should be in a module format that RequireJS can understand**. Exception to the rule: if you are using the r.js Node adapter, the modules can be in the traditional CommonJS module format. You can use the CommonJS converter tool if you need to convert traditional CommonJS modules into the async module format that RequireJS uses.

(Emphasis added.)

This is not something that RequireJS understands:

```
exports.bar = '1234';
exports.xyz = function noop() {};
```

It would have to be:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    exports.bar = '1234';
    exports.xyz = function noop() {};
});
```

Either you do this conversion manually or you use [`r.js -convert`](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html#autoconversion) to do the conversion for you.